# 2 resources relation - select each record for each record - even if pivot doesn't define it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 resources: users and privileges - and there is also some connecting table like `user_privilege`

So my structure looks like this:

```
user
user_id, name
1        John
2        Daniel
3        Paul


privilege
privilege_id, name
1             Perm 1
2             Perm 2
3             Perm 3

user_privilege
user_id, privilege_id
1        1
1        2
2        1
```

And if there is record in user_privilege that means user has this privilege.

But I also want to select privileges which user doesn't have.

It's easy to select all given privileges

But I want output like:

```
privilege_id, user_id, has
1             1        true
2             1        true
3             1        false
1             2        true
2             2        false
3             2        false
1             3        false
2             3        false
3             3        false
```

So actually it's something like each privilege for each user - but with information if user has this privilege or not.

I want to to this in Posgres db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a cross join between `user` and `privilege` and then do an outer join to `user_privilege` to test if that user has the privilege

```
select au.user_id, au.privilege_id,
       up.privilege_id is not null as has_priv
from (
  select u.user_id, p.privilege_id
  from "user" u
    cross join privilege p
) au
  left join user_privilege up on (au.user_id, au.privilege_id) = (up.user_id, up.privilege_id)
order by user_id, privilege_id
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0177c06cc423c1d15c191fbcb4bc10e6)